# How can I dynamically include one of several AngularJS partials depending on the route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a music app which has urls of the form `my-app.com/[0-9]{10}`, like so:

```
my-app.com/0123456789
my-app.com/1293938388
```

Each one of these is either a song, a playlist, or a user page, and I can query the backend to figure out which one. However, since these URLs are not distinguishable without querying the database, I can't do the normal `$routeProvider.when('route-prefix/:routeArgument')` to instantiate a different partial for each one.

I'd like to be able to specify a default handler which shows a spinner and queries the database, and then include one of a number of partials and with one of a number of controllers based on the type of the response.

What's the right way to do this in angular? Should I be using `ng-include`? I would like it if the inactive controllers didn't execute at all, which is why the obvious solution of using a partial with multiple `ng-controller` directives doesn't seem right.

Thanks!

Comment: [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) (based on route) with ng-include is probably what you want.

Comment: @MarkRajcok If there are multiple ng-includes inside the different branches of an ng-switch, will they all be instantiated, or will only the ng-switch-when which is actually chosen be instantiated/processed?

Comment: Only the ng-switch-when that matches.  ng-switch (unlike ng-show/ng-hide) actually adds/removes DOM elements.

Comment: Sweet, thanks, I guess there's my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) can be used conditionally add or remove content from the DOM, based on the route.  (This is in contrast to ng-show/ng-hide, which currently only modify CSS properties to show or hide content that is always in the DOM).